# ExtJS ComboBox validation returns unexpected result

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, string

I've just been working on a ExtJS script and I have a ComboBox which has

```
allowBlank = false
```

and

```
forceSelection = true
```

I have an item in the list which acts as a default message which has a display text

```
Please select...
```

and no value

```
''
```

When I run validate on the ComboBox I get **true**
No idea why?
According to the documentation when

```
allowBlank = false
```

the validation is forced to check for value.length > 0
So I have done my own test in the JS Console

```
>> if (thisForm.controlManager.controlArray[2].allowBlanks) { if (thisForm.controlManager.controlArray[2].length >= 0) { true; } false; } else { if (thisForm.controlManager.controlArray[2].length > 0) { true; } false; }
```

and it returned **false** 
So I thought it might a bug in validate method so I tried doing this

```
>> thisForm.controlManager.controlArray[2].validateValue('')
```

and got this as a result **true**

Any one have any kind of idea of what I might be doing wrong or if anything else needs set to get this validate to return false when value is ''.

PS. I've also tried this

```
>> thisForm.controlManager.controlArray[2].validateValue(' ')
```

and got the correct result which is **false**. This made me very confused as I would normally expect '' and ' ' to return the same value in validation.

I know that a workaround would be to set my value to ' ' but I would rather get it working with ''.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the emptyText configuration
Ext have this code for validate fields:

```
validate : function(){
    if(this.disabled || this.validateValue(this.processValue(this.getRawValue()))){
        this.clearInvalid();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and getRawValue is defined like this:

```
getRawValue : function(){
    var v = this.rendered ? this.el.getValue() : Ext.value(this.value, '');
    if(v === this.emptyText){
        v = '';
    }
    return v;
}
```

so, if the value is equal to the empty text, the returned value is ''

Comment: Thank's that has given me an insight of what is going on under the hood. I overridden the isValid function to use this.getValue() instead of this.getRawValue() as this method gets display text instead of the value.. Pretty weird. I also overridden the validateValue method to do the following:
`if(!a.preventMark)
{
 if(c)
 {
  if (a.allowBlanks)
  {
   a.clearInvalid();
  }
  else
  {
   if (b.length > 0)
   {
    a.clearInvalid();
   }
   else
   {
    d = "You must select a valid value!";
    a.markInvalid(d);
    c = false;
   }
  }
 }
 else
 {
  a.markInvalid(d);
 }
 
 return c;
}`

Comment: got an even better way for anyone interested, override isValid to use getValue instead of getRawValue and then override getErrors as this does nothing by default so by changing this there is no need to change validateValue :) A lot cleaner and more suitable approach!

Answer (score 2):

I just so happened to end up grappling with this same issue, and after some looking around, managed to find a solution which does not require overriding Extjs's standard functionality.

Basically, there is a 'validator' config option for descendents of Ext.form.field.Text which allows programmers to specify a custom validation function for a component (see [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validator)).

Basically, your validator function gets called at the start of getErrors() and is evaluated before the rest of the field's standard validation.  The validator function takes one argument (the value) and must return either true if the value is valid or an error message string if it is not.

The following config ended up working for my case:

```
validator: function (value) {
  return (value === '/*Your emptytext text*/') ? "blankText" : true;
}
```